# Startup error Logstash (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)

Tags: ubuntu, logstash

My operating system is Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed Logstash and I try to run it with a command:

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.
```

But I get a startup error:

```
[ERROR] 2018-05-12 20:54:15.228 [main] Logstash - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: 
(OpenSSL::X509::StoreError) setting default path failed: the 
trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

The configuration file:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"
    topics = ["cpu_metrics"]
    enable_auto_commit = "true"
    type = "cpu"
  }
}
output {
  if [type] == "cpu" {
    file {
      path => "/home/cpu/cpu.log"
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and based on this:

http://10minbasics.com/logstash-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty/

Following commands helped me:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from following Ziemowit's answer, I had to update my ubuntu's ca-certificates-java too:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

After that,  the error went away.